# Android toLowerCase() issue with accented characters

Tags: java, android, non-ascii-characters, lowercase

My app has a feature to filter content based on some keywords.
This is case insensitive so in order to work I first call `String.toLowerCase()` on the source content.

The issue I have is when the source is in upper case and contains accentuated characters like with the french word: "INVITÉ"

This word when set to `lowercase` using the device default locale returns "invité"
The problem is that the last character is not the same as the lowercase character "é"
Instead it's the combination of 2 chars:
"e" 101 &
" ' " 769

Because of this "invité" does not match "invité"

How can I solve this? I would prefer not to remove accentuated characters altogether

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should normalize the string like this.

```
String upper = "INVITÉ";
System.out.println(upper + " length=" + upper.length());
String lower = upper.toLowerCase();
System.out.println(lower + " length=" + lower.length());
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(lower, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
System.out.println(normalized + " length=" + normalized.length());
```

output:

```
INVITÉ length=7
invité length=7
invité length=6
```

It also works for Japanese.

```
String japanese = "が";
System.out.println(japanese + " length=" + japanese.length());
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(japanese, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
System.out.println(normalized + " length=" + normalized.length());
```

output:

```
が length=2
が length=1
```

Comment: Will this work in every existing language including Japanese, Chinese, ...?